# Product of consecutive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've found this simple problem tricky: let $l$ and $s$ be integers, in particular $l$ is non-negative. The question is: if $l(l+1)=s(s+1)$, then either $s=l$ or $s=-l-1$.
I've been thinking that consecutive numbers don't have common prime factors, but it's not useful. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried factorizing the expression? Based on the conclusion, it should look something like $(s-l) ( s+l+1)$, maybe with additional terms around.

Comment: Somebody seems to have downvoted all three answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expand $l(l+1)=s(s+1)$ to get $l^2+l=s^2+s.$  Subtracting $l^2+l$ from both sides, we get $$s^2+s-l^2-l=0.$$

Now, if we treat $l$ as a constant, then the equation $s^2+s-l^2-l=0$ is in fact a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ where $a=1,b=1,$ and $c=-(l^2+l).$

Using the quadratic formula on this expression, we get $$s=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4(-(l^2+l))}}{2}=\frac{-1 \pm (2l+1)}{2}.$$  This means that $s=l$ or $s=-l-1.$

Answer (score 2):

If $l$ is given, then $l(l+1)=s(s+1)$ is a quadratic equation in $s$. A quadratic equation has at most two solutions; and you can check that $s=l$ and $s=-l-1$ are solutions. So they are the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $x(x+1); x> 0$ is strictly increasing.

So if $n = l(l+1)$ and $l > 0$ there is only one possible option for $l$.

So as $l > 0$ and $l(l+1) = s(s+1)$ either $l =s$ or $s$ is not positive.

If $s$ is not positive but $l(l+1)$ is, we must have both $s, s+1$ negative.

And we have $l(l+1) = s(s+1) = |s|\cdot |s+1|$.

As $s, s+1 < 0$ then $|s| = -s = (-s -1) +1 = |s+1| +1$.

So $l(l+1) = |s+1|\cdot( |s+1|+1)$ where $l, |s+1|>0$ and so

$l = |s+1| = -s-1; s=-l-1$